# Git config: private remote url

Tags: git

How to override [remote "origin"] url set in .git/config?
Sometimes I need to use an https protocol with my username and password as part of the url and I wouldn't like to commit such information. One option is to ignore .git/config.
Is there a way to:
a) override it (from global .gitconfig?), or
b) have a local .git/config but without worrying it could be commited, or
d) have an alias to `git push https://privateurl master`, or
c) have it working in some other way?

Comment: Why would you add/commit your `.git/config` file, or anything in `.git/`, in the first place?

Comment: .git/config is not committed nor pushed. It holds local settings locally. You can also just change it as necessary (git remote set-url origin https://....) or just use a temporary remote for push: git push https://....x.git master

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are misunderstanding how Git works. The files in your .git directory store the information Git needs to operate. This includes repository information (commits, objects, pointers etc) as well as meta information (the local index, local preferences and so on). Files inside the .git directory aren't stored in the repository, as they essentially *are* the repository. Meta information (such as settings in .git/config) will not be pushed to remote repositories.

See [this](http://book.git-scm.com/1_git_directory_and_working_directory.html) entry in the Git Community Book for a (brief) overview of the .git directory, and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7523152/is-it-dangerous-to-include-your-googlecode-password-in-git-config) for further discussion.

Answer (score 3):

You can add insteadOf in your $HOME/.gitconfig

Eg.

```
[url "https://git.host.com"]
      insteadOf = "git://git.host.com"
```

or

```
[url "ssh://user@git.host.com"]
    insteadOf = "git://git.host.com"
```

And this will add your username for ssh.

```
[url "ssh://user@git.host.com"]
    insteadOf = "ssh://git.host.com"
```

Comment: +1 for an interesting feature of the config file - but its not really necessary to solve this issue.